# Unable to append quote sign in terminal out put for offset sequence

Tags: command-line, bash

I have following offset addresses saved inside a file placed at desktop.

```
eagle@max-pc:~$cat ~/Desktop/offset.txt 
0x00000000
0x00000419
0x0000073d
0x00000a24
0x000011cf
0x0000139c
...
```

Now I want to add quotes at the end of each offset address using terminal, when ever I try my output changed into

```
eagle@max-pc:~$for i in `cat ~/Desktop/offset.txt `; do echo $i"\"";done
```

output now,

```
"x00000000
"x00000419
"x0000073d
"x00000a24
"x000011cf
"x0000139c
"x00001568
```

can you please guide me where I'm doing it wrong? I have tried various methods including different combination of echo and it's arguments, printf.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use sed.

```
sed 's/$/"/' ~/Desktop/offset.txt
```

`$` matches the end of a line. So by replacing the boundary which exists at the last with double quotes will give you the desired output.

Example:

```
$ echo '0x00000000
> 0x00000419' | sed 's/$/"/'
0x00000000"
0x00000419"
```

Add the inline edit `-i` paramter to save the changes made to that file.

```
sed -i 's/$/"/' ~/Desktop/offset.txt
```

Some other methods in awk.

```
$ echo '0x00000000
0x00000419' | awk '{$0=$0"\""}1'
0x00000000"
0x00000419"
$ echo '0x00000000
0x00000419' | awk '{sub(/$/, "\"")}1'
0x00000000"
0x00000419"
$ echo '0x00000000
0x00000419' | awk '{print $0"\""}'
0x00000000"
0x00000419"
```

**OR**

```
while read -r i; do sed 's/$/"/' <<< "$i"; done < ~/Desktop/offset.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, Perhaps I need output at terminal and I have used a variable `$i`; I have tried but no success by using following code sequence. `for i in `cat ~/Desktop/offset.txt `; do echo '$i'| sed 's/$/"/';done`. Currently my motivation is to append text by using variable and terminal commands.

Comment: sed parses the whole file line by line. So you don't need to have the for command.

Comment: Same results for every command. Quote sign is appending in start when I have used variable.

Comment: Motivation is to provide output at terminal without using file, Isn't possible to do such operation with `echo` or `printf` with the help of `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: see my update. Sorry i didn't get your motivation.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the original question is not clear but I **think** the OP's issue is that the quote character is getting prepended rather than appended regardless of the tool that is used - I don't know how (the only thing I can think of is that it is related to a right-to-left language or locale setting).